# Por que a comparação de objetos com mesmo conteúdo é falsa?

Tags: javascript, objetos, comparação

Por que essa condição é definida como falsa?

[image: Demonstrando o resultado]

Coloquei imagem por estar utilizando o console do Google e o código não precisar ser executado já que a dúvida é conceitual.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Objetos são tipos por referência, portanto os valores básicos dos objetos são ponteiros que indicam onde o valor do objeto realmente está, é uma forma de [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101).

Quando manda comparar os valores das variáveis o comparação é feita entre ponteiros. Se você tem dois objetos diferentes é certo que eles estão em endereços de memórias diferentes, então obviamente os ponteiros contidos nessas variáveis são diferentes, por isso é falso.

O conteúdo dos objetos podem ser iguais, mas isso é uma coincidência, os objetos são diferentes, não é feita uma comparação com o conteúdo do objeto em si.

Podem existir exceções, por exemplo o tipo `String` que é uma referência, mas tem semântica de tipo por valor, então a comparação passa ser feita em cima do conteúdo do objeto e não a sua referência, mas foi definido explicitamente que seria feito assim, não é o normal.